# Does glassdoor.com (or similar company rating services) offer an API?

Tags: glassdoor.com

I'd like to access (crowd-sourced) company rating information programmatically. Does anybody have suggestions which companies offer an API for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glassdoor does not offer a *public* API. There are widgets available on their syndication page http://www.glassdoor.com/about/syndicationCenter.htm

Searching a few times brings up this signup wall.

[image: Facebook signup for Glassdoor]

So I guess that are wary of scrapers.

Searching similar sites seems to show that there is no API released for those sites as well but widgets instead.

Answer (score 0):

Glassdoor does offer an API, you can see it in use [here](http://fool.com/quote/nasdaq/appl/aapl).  From what I understand, it's still a private API, and you'd have to contact Glassdoor for access. We use it for the company information on our stock quote pages.

Answer (score 0):

I recently released an opensource Glassdoor API (using Python requests and BeautifulSoup) https://github.com/hackerlist/glassdoor.

EDIT: http://www.glassdoor.com/api/index.htm -- glassdoor now offers a public REST API which requires a key.